# Como faço para limpar o Input após salvar os dados?

Tags: react-native

```
export default class Calculo extends Component{

    constructor(props){
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            data: '',
            horario: '',
            ctTotalInput: '',
            ldlInput: '',
            hdlInput: '',
            vldlInput: ''            
        }

        this.salvarDados = this.salvarDados.bind(this)
    }

    salvarDados = () => {
      let state = this.state

      db.transaction(function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql(
          'INSERT INTO AppMedico ( ColesTotal, ColesLDL, ColesHDL, ColesVLDL) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
          [ state.ctTotalInput, state.ldlInput, state.hdlInput, state.vldlInput],
          (tx, results) => {
            alert('Results', results.rowsAffected)
            if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
              Alert(
                'Registered Successfully'
              )
            } else {
              alert('Registration Failed');
            }
          }
        )
      })
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Historico')
    }

    componentDidMount(){
      let date = new Date().getDate(); //Current Date
      let month = new Date().getMonth() + 1; //Current Month
      let year = new Date().getFullYear(); //Current Year
      let hours = new Date().getHours(); //Current Hours
      let min = new Date().getMinutes(); //Current Minutes
      let sec = new Date().getSeconds(); //Current Seconds

      let s = this.state
      s.data = `${date}/${month}/${year}`
      s.horario = `${hours}:${min}:${sec}`
      this.setState(s)
    }

    render(){
        return(

          <View style={styles.container}>

            <Text style={styles.text}> Informe os valores do exame </Text>

            <Item floatingLabel style={styles.area}>
              <Label> Colesterol Total </Label>
              <Input  keyboardType="numeric" value={this.state.ctTotalInput} onChangeText={(ctTotalInput) => this.setState({ctTotalInput})}/>
            </Item>

            <Item floatingLabel style={styles.area}>
              <Label> Colesterol LDL </Label>
              <Input  keyboardType="numeric" value={this.state.ldlInput} onChangeText={(ldlInput) => this.setState({ldlInput})}/>
            </Item>

            <Item floatingLabel style={styles.area}>
              <Label> Colesterol HDL </Label>
              <Input  keyboardType="numeric" value={this.state.hdlInput} onChangeText={(hdlInput) => this.setState({hdlInput})}/>
            </Item>

            <Item floatingLabel style={styles.area}>
              <Label> Colesterol VLDL </Label>
              <Input  keyboardType="numeric" value={this.state.vldlInput} onChangeText={(vldlInput) => this.setState({vldlInput})}/>
            </Item>

            <View style={styles.areaButton}>
              <Button style={styles.button} onPress={this.salvarDados}>
                <Text> Salvar </Text>
              </Button>
            </View>

          </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Toda vez que você altera um valor no input, o seu state é atualizado, como o state está vinculado com o input, o que você precisa fazer depois de salvar é apagar os valores do state, isso deve atualizar sua tela

```js
salvarDados = () => {
  let state = this.state

  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql(
      'INSERT INTO AppMedico ( ColesTotal, ColesLDL, ColesHDL, ColesVLDL) VALUES (?,?,?,?)',
      [ state.ctTotalInput, state.ldlInput, state.hdlInput, state.vldlInput],
      (tx, results) => {
        alert('Results', results.rowsAffected)
        if (results.rowsAffected > 0) {
          Alert(
            'Registered Successfully'
          )
        } else {
          alert('Registration Failed');
        }
      }
    )
  })
 this.setState({ data: '', horario: '', ctTotalInput: '', ldlInput: '', hdlInput: '', vldlInput: '' })
               
  }
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Historico')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Após utilizar os valores é só mudar o valor com `this.setState({name:''})`, ***exemplo***:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        name: 'algum valor'
      }
      this.limpar = this.limpar.bind(this);
  }
  limpar() {
      this.setState({name:''});      
  }
  render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <input type="text" value={this.state.name} />
          <button onClick={this.limpar}>Limpar</button>
        </div>
      )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

<sup>Ref. [React Native - State](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/state)</sup>